# DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = True not working?

Tags: apex, duplicate-management, dmloptions

I've currently enabled duplicate rules for the Contact object and specified the "Action on Create" and "Action on Edit" to "Block" incoming duplicate Contact records.

When testing with the example code provided in current documentation for the [`DmlOptions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm) Class I'm still getting duplicate errors when trying to insert a duplicate contact record:

```
Contact duplicate_contact = new Contact(firstName='Bob', 
                                        lastName='Duplicate',
                                        email='test@test.org');

Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions(); 
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.runAsCurrentUser = true;
Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(duplicate_contact, dml);
if (sr.isSuccess()) {
    System.debug('Duplicate contact has been inserted in Salesforce!');
}
else system.debug('>>> Error Inserting Duplicate: '+ sr.getErrors());
```

Error Received:

> You're creating a duplicate record. We recommend you use an existing record instead.

Anyone know why specifying `duplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true` would still produce this error?

Comment: @BrandOR: I just created standard duplicate rule on **Contact** and then used your exact code in anonymous code and it is working.

Comment: @Mahmood - Try setting the action to _Block_ on the duplicate rule and then specifying the `allowSave` header. If it's set to block this will cause duplicate inserts to fail even when `allowSave = true`

Comment: Thats what I did, set the duplicate rule action to **block**, and it was saved.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually working as designed. The `DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave` option is really allowing for bypassing of the duplicate rule alert. If the duplicate rule specifies a blocking action this will block any and all duplicates found even when specifying `AllowSave = true`.

There has been a documentation bug filed for this issue.